# In git how we can checkout a branch while creating it only if it does not exist already?

Tags: git

So `git checkout -B <branch>` does not fit the bill, because it would force the  onto the current HEAD, even if the  exists already and points somewhere else.

I want a different behavior. If the branch exists - checkout, if not - create at the current HEAD and then checkout.

My current solution (in Powershell) is:

```
$CreateBranch = $null
git show-ref --verify --quiet "refs/remotes/origin/$BranchName"
if ($LASTEXITCODE)
{
    $CreateBranch = "-B"
}
git checkout $CreateBranch $BranchName
```

Is there a shorter way?

**EDIT 1**

I have been thinking about the way I defined the question and the comments have helped me realize I need to disambiguate a few points. So:

1. The repository is examined after `git fetch --force --tags --prune origin`
2. If the **remote tracking** branch exists, then this is what should be checked out.
3. A local branch without the respective remote should be ignored.
4. If both the local and remote tracking branches exist, the local branch must be checked out at the **remote tracking** - it must be realigned.

Now I can see my approach is wrong, because it does not meet these points. Thank you for all the commenters who pointed out at these aspects.

Comment: `git checkout $BranchName || git checkout -b $BranchName` or the powershell equivalent of that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer the first one would create the branch if it doesn't exist locally and there's a remote branch with that name so it wouldn't fit the requirement.

Comment: unless we assume that's never the case, of course.

Comment: What? `git checkout SomeBranch` never creates the branch. Actually I should have used `switch` to avoid the ambiguity of `checkout`:  `git switch $BranchName || git switch -c $BranchName`

Comment: What? Of course it does! Try running `git checkout` specifying the name of a branch that does not exist locally and is present on _one remote_ only.

Comment: According to your PowerShell snippet, the logic is as follows: • If `origin/$BranchName` **exist**: Checkout the branch `$BranchName`. *Note that `$BranchName` is not necessarily up-to-date with `origin/$BranchName`.*
• If `origin/$BranchName` **does not exist**: a) Checkout a new branch `$BranchName` from the current *HEAD* (in case `$BranchName` does not exist) or b) reset (by force!) and checkout the existing `$BranchName` branch to/at the current *HEAD*. **Is this really what you intend to do?**

Comment: @JoachimSauer answer is the correct one, please write it as an answer.

Comment: @Matt - Actually, this is exactly what I need to do. The repository is fully checked out during the CI build, so this makes it easier. In short - yes, this is the logic I want.

Comment: @Matt - I revised my opinion. You are right. Please, see **EDIT 1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid having `git checkout` (or the new `git switch`) use the DWIM mode to *create* branch `$b` from `$remote/$b` (for any $b and $remote for which this would happen), use the `--no-guess` flag.  This flag was new in Git 2.21.  (`git switch` itself was new in Git 2.23, so if you have `git switch` at all, you have `--no-guess`.)

You still need at least two commands to get what you want, but you no longer need an explicit verification that `refs/heads/$b` exists first.

If your Git predates 2.21, do the explicit verification:

```
git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/heads/$branchname
```

If this fails (exit code 1), `$branchname` is not an existing branch name.  If it succeeds (exit code 0), `$branchname` is an existing branch name.  Proceed from there.

Note that your PowerShell fragment suggests that you want a behavior that is different from what you described in your text.  You do not care whether some *local* branch exists, but rather whether some particular *remote-tracking name* exists.  Use the `git rev-parse` method for that as well; just replace `refs/heads/$b` with `refs/remotes/$o/$b` where `$o` and `$b` are set appropriately.

---

Re the edit:

> The repository is examined after git fetch --force --tags --prune origin.

OK.  Note that this uses the existing `remote.origin.fetch` refspecs (which is likely to be fine).

> If the remote tracking branch exists, then this is what should be checked out.

Is this for some fixed branch name, or set of branch names?  (Not sure how to write a loop in PowerShell; it would be `for branch in name1 name2 name3; do ...; done` in sh/bash.)  Or, do you want to enumerate all remote-tracking names and/or all local branch names?  (`git for-each-ref` is the general Git name-enumeration tool.)

> A local branch without the respective remote should be ignored.

If you're enumerating all names in `refs/remotes/origin/` (all `origin/*` remote-tracking names), this happens "for free"; if you're enumerating some set of fixed names, or enumerating local branch names, it requires some kind of test, of course.

Note that it's conventional, in a Git repository (though much rarer in a CI-system repository), to have (local) branch names have some *upstream* set.  To find the upstream of some local branch, use `git rev-parse` with the `@{upstream}` or `@{u}` suffix: `git rev-parse dev@{u}` will test whether `dev` has an upstream set, and error out if not.  If it does have an upstream set, rev-parse will go on to handle it as usual, turning that upstream name into a hash ID or symbolic name depending on flags.

This general idea (of having a single upstream) does not work well in triangular work-flows, where we like to pick up new commits from repository **R**, but submit new commits to different repository **S**.  If it doesn't fit with your own set of tasks, don't use it.

> If both the local and remote tracking branches exist, the local branch must be checked out at the remote tracking - it must be realigned.

That would be the `-B` or `-C` (checkout or switch respectively) action.

So, assuming some fixed set of names, the sh/bash variant of this would be:

```bash
fatal() {
    ... insert code here to print an error message and abort ...
}
for name in $list_of_names; do
    # Determine whether origin/$name exists at all.  If
    # not, skip this name.  While we're at it, save the
    # hash ID since we will want it in a moment.
    hash=$(git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/remotes/origin/$name) || continue
    # The remote-tracking name exists.  What about as a local
    # branch name?  If not, do a detached checkout of $hash, but
    # if so, do a forcible reset of the local name to $hash.
    if git rev-parse --quiet --verify refs/heads/$name >/dev/null; then
        # forcible reset:
        git switch -C $name $hash ||
           fatal "unable to locally reset $name to $hash"
    else
        # detached-HEAD check-out:
        git switch --detach $hash ||
           fatal "unable to detach HEAD to $hash"
    fi
    ... do some operation with the checked-out files ...
done
```

The whole process seems a bit fishy: if we need to do some action with some specific commits as determined by some specific names, we can just do a detached-HEAD checkout of each such name, as long as we don't ever need to make *new* commits.  And, if we *do* need to make *new* commits, we probably don't ever want any detached-HEAD checkouts *unless* we're going to try a build (this is a CI system after all) and *if it succeeds*, stick a computer-generated name *on* it (e.g., some automated-build-tag) ... which again works fine with detached-HEAD mode.

Though I know nothing of the CI system in question, it seems to me that we either want to just build (and then maybe make a build tarball or whatever out of the result), or see if there's already an automated build of `$hash` and if not, make one and tag it as "automated build of $hash".  If there could be multiple CI systems building in parallel, we would probably like to add some sort of parallel-build-coordinator so that we know which builds are in progress, which ones have failed and don't need to be retried, and so on: a sort of Build Broker.  (All of that of course falls well outside things *Git* does.)

Comment: My git is new. Can you show how would you use `git swtch`? I have never heard of this command before.

Comment: @mark: `git switch` is basically just half (or so) of `git checkout`: the "safe" half, that switches to some particular branch or commit, or says that it can't because that would wreck some in-progress work. The other half-or-so of `git checkout`—the half where you say *please wreck all the in-progress work in this directory* by running `git checkout dev` when `dev` is the name of a directory, not a branch—is in `git restore`. Using the two new commands means you can't accidentally run `git switch dev` while dev isn't a branch name but is a directory, and thus destroy work in `dev`.

Comment: I need some time to grok it.

Comment: After some thinking I added **EDIT 1** to clarify. Essentially I accept the feedback some commenters provided. I apologize for updating the question after you have provided such a detailed response. Would you be able to edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: there is no `-B` option available for switch. we may need to use `-C` to create branch

Comment: @WBGUY001: oops, yes, I use `git checkout` so often (nearly 15 years of habits from before "git switch" existed...) that I sometimes use the wrong option letter.